# Error 404 in Vercel after deploy backend aplication using express and mongodb

Tags: express, deployment, build, vercel

After realize my deploy in vercel i have this error: 404: NOT_FOUND
Code: NOT_FOUND

Nothing is wrong if my logs in vercel, and im alreary put the versel.json config as a documentation tell.

I've also put it as "builds" in package.json

Here it's my vercel.json.

```
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/api/(.*)", "destination": "/api" }]
}
```

Here it's my index.mjs

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import userRouter from './routes/user.route.js';
import authRouter from './routes/auth.route.js';
import listingRouter from './routes/listing.route.js';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import path from 'path';
dotenv.config();

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB!');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

const __dirname = path.resolve();

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.use(cookieParser());

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 3000!');
});

app.use('/api/user', userRouter);
app.use('/api/auth', authRouter);
app.use('/api/listing', listingRouter);


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'dist')));


app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'dist', 'index.html'));
})

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  const statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  const message = err.message || 'Internal Server Error';
  return res.status(statusCode).json({
    success: false,
    statusCode,
    message,
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use It

vercel.json

```
{
"version": 2,
"builds": [{
    "src": "./index.js",
    "use": "@vercel/node"
}],
"routes": [{
    "src": "/(.*)",
    "dest": "index.js"
}]}
```

.env file

```
MONGODB_URI = your db url
```